# Cordova 3.8.0 runnning on iPhone6 with 320x568px - Scaling Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, web, iphone-6

A new Cordova HelloWorld application with Cordova 5.0.0 and iOs 3.8.0 deployed via Xcode on iPhone 6 runnns with 320x568px instead of 375x667px.

### Further information on this issue:

1. runs in the simulator just fine
2. issue was found on my "older" current project, which should be updated for iPhone6. This project started with Cordova 3.5. Found the bugreport on apache cordova. First: Tried the bugfixe suggestions -> no success. Second: Updated Cordova -> no success.
3. after these steps I downloaded the HelloWorld application to try if it works with completely new project -> no success.

Comment: The HTML metagtag is set up accordingly to the Apple dev Guide.

Comment: Debugging the Objective-C code show that the detected resolution of the screen is 320x568px. This causes then also the webview and its content to this resolution. Changing the detected resolution manually to 375x667px causes the webview to render partly out of the visible screen.

Answer (score 1):

if your app is running in this resolution on an iPhone 6 you have two possible reasons:
- the phone is in compatibility mode (I assume not)
- you did not provide a LaunchScreen-Storyboard in your project or a fitting LaunchImage for the dimensions.

If you do not provide a LaunchScreen-Storyboard or a large LaunchImage for this resolution, the app will run automatically in compatibility mode.

Comment: I set the launch screen in xcode via an asset catalog, like a regular ios app -> no success. I also tried to set a launch screen in the config.xml with the images in the "Resources/splash" folder -> no success. Last option was to reference the Launch Screens in the Info.plist file like the HelloWorld app -> no success

Comment: In your asset catalog do you have images that are called Retina HD 5.5 and Retina HD 4.7? If not delete the LaunchImage from the asset catalog and add a new one, it should bring you the new sizes by default

Comment: I have set the two images with the expected sizes. Do you also mean the filename has to be "Retina HD 5.5" ?

Comment: How can the compatibility mode be detected?

Comment: The file name does not matter. XCode would complain if the sizes do not match the expected size by  a warning. For your phone it is in settings - display & brightness - display zoom. For your app the easiest is if you open the keyboard in an input field and compare with Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Totally different problem. The option "Adjust the text size at Settings > Display & Brightness > Text Size" was activated. (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203073)